# npm error after updating to Meteor 0.8.1.1

Tags: meteor, npm, connect

After attempting to update to Meteor 0.8.1.1, I get an npm error that it cannot unlock connect@2.9.0.  I have removed and re-added iron-router, to no avail.  Have also run npm cache clean, per another stackoverflow solution suggested to a similar problem.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock connect@2.9.0, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR!     at unlock (/home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1304:11)
npm ERR!     at cb (/home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:646:5)
npm ERR!     at /home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:655:20
npm ERR!     at /home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1290:7
npm ERR!     at /home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:167:38
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.Req.done (/home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:144:5)
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.done (/home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:64:22)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-61-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/bin/node" "/home/twisted/.meteor/tools/43b8566b9f/bin/npm" "install" "--force" "connect@2.9.0"
npm ERR! cwd /home/twisted/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/d1ffb3f06ea4c112132b030f2eb1a70b81675ecb/.npm/package-new-1u1tvv2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/twisted/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/d1ffb3f06ea4c112132b030f2eb1a70b81675ecb/.npm/package-new-1u1tvv2/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors while scanning packages:

While building package `iron-router`:
error: couldn't install npm package
```

Comment: Can't help you, but I'm seeing the exact same thing.

Comment: Tyler:  Try upgrading using privileged access (sudo in Linux).  That cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, verify that your `.npm` directory doesn't contain subdirectories that are owned by `root`:

```
find ~/.npm -type d -exec ls -ld {} \; | grep root
```

If it does, you probably executed some `sudo npm` command at some point in the past.  To fix this, update your directory permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
```

If that doesn't work, try upgrading to the latest version of npm:

```
npm update npm -g
```

If that doesn't work, try running `sudo meteor` to see if meteor will successfully update all of your outdated npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor wraps npm dependancies inside each package. Try going to `/home/twisted/.meteorite/packages/iron-router` and deleting the `iron-router` package. Afterwards run `mrt update` and then try running you app again. That should clean up your issue. Sadly I was unable to reproduce this when I upgrade a app with IronRouter installed. If you are still having this issue please post which version of IronRouter you are using.

Comment: Tried that but didn't get success.

Comment: Interesting, I had assumed it was a mrt issue. Can you reproduce the issue with a clean app? I would not recommend using superuser unless you have super rights on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I now need to run updates and certain package adds as the superuser, whereas I didn't before the upgrade.